How can I prove that $|A - B| = |A| - |B|$ where $B\subseteq A$
I denote the cardinality of a set $S$ as $|S|$. Now, how do I show that if $B\subseteq A$, then $|A - B| = |A| - |B|$? For this proof, I tried induction on the cardinality of $B$. Suppose that $|B| = 0$. I've already proved that this implies that $B = \phi$. Thus, the LHS becomes $|A - \phi| = |A|$. The RHS becomes $|A| - |B| = |A| - 0 = |A|$. So, LHS = RHS and the base case is shown.
But I'm not quite sure how to proceed forward. I tried using the lemma (this is already proven) that $|X - \{x\}| = |X| - 1$ where $x\in X$ but to no avail. Even trying to use the lemma $|X\cup\{x\}| = |X| + 1$ where $x\not\in X$ gave me no solution. Is there a way I can go about this task?

$A$ is the disjoint union of $B$ and $A-B$.

Use that in general, $~|E| + |F| - |E \cap F| = |E \cup F|.$
Setting $~E = A-B, ~F = B,~$ and using that $ ~B \subseteq A,$
you have that $~E \cap F = \emptyset.~$
Further, since $~B \subseteq A,~$ every element in $~B~$ is also in $~A.$  Therefore, $~E \cup F = A.$ 
That is, every element in $~A~$ is either not in $~B~$ or is in $~B.$
Therefore,
$$|A-B| + |B| - 0 = |A| \implies |A - B| = |A| - |B|.$$

dang that was simple

The general strategy for proving this by induction is as follows:
Let the statement be true for $|B|\leq k$ and for all $|A| \leq m$ where $k,m\geq 1$. Now, we must do the inductive step on both $k$ and $m$. That is, we should prove two statements: for $|B| = k+1,|A|=m$ and for $|B|=k,|A|=m+1$. Once we have proved these two statements, and we have the base case true for $|A|=1,|B|=1$, we have inductively proved for all lengths.
To prove for $|B|=k+1,|A|=m$: because $|A|$ did not change, it must be that the added element $t$ was already in $A$, but was not in $B$. This means that $t\in(A-B)$. Thus,
$$\begin{aligned}
|A-B^\prime|=|A-(B\cup\{t\})|&=|(A-B)-\{t\}| &\\
&=|(A-B)|-|\{t\}| & \text{inductive hypothesis, }\{t\}\subseteq A-B\\
&=|A|-|B|-1\\
&=|A|-(|B|+1)\\
&=|A|-|B\cup\{t\}|\\
&=|A|-|B^\prime|
\end{aligned}$$
Similarly, for $|B|=k,|A|=m+1$: because $|B|$ did not change, it must be that the added element $t$ did not go into $B$.Thus,
$$
\begin{aligned}
|A^\prime-B| = |(A\cup\{t\})-B| &= |(A-B)\cup(\{t\}-B)|\\
&=|A-B|+|\{t\}-B|&\text{These sets are disjoint because $t\not\in A$}\\
&&\text{Using $|U\cup V|=|U|+|V|-|U\cap V|$}\\
&=|A|-|B|+1 = |A\cup{t}|-|B|\\
&=|A^\prime|-|B|
\end{aligned}
$$
With this, we can extend this from $m=k=1$ to all natural numbers.

Now as $B \subseteq A$ so $(A \cap B^{C})\cup B = (A \cup B) \cap (B^{c} \cup B) = (A \cup B) = A$. It is trivial to see that $(A \cap B^{c}) \cap B = \phi$ so $|(A \cap B^{c}) \cap B| = 0$.
Finally,
$|A| = |A \cap B^{C}| +  |B| - |(A \cap B^{c}) \cap B| \implies |A \cap B^{C}| = |A| - |B| \implies |A - B| = |A| - |B|$

To prove that if ⊆, then ∣−∣=∣∣−∣∣.
Proof
Let  be a finite set.
Let B be a subset of (i.e., B⊆A).
Since B⊆A, every element of B is also an element of A.
The set A can be partitioned into two disjoint subsets:
A−B and B.
A−B is the set of elements in A that are not in B.
B is the set of elements in A that are in B.
The cardinality of a set, ∣S∣, is the number of elements in the set S.
If S and T are disjoint sets (i.e., S∩T=∅), then the cardinality of their union is the sum of their cardinalities:
∣S∪T∣=∣S∣+∣T∣.
Apply the Cardinality Principle:
Since A can be partitioned into A−B and B, and these two sets are disjoint (i.e., (A−B)∩B=∅), we have:
A=(A−B)∪B
By the principle of cardinality for disjoint sets:
∣A∣=∣A−B∣+∣B∣
Solve for ∣A−B∣:
To find the cardinality of
A−B, we can rearrange the equation:
∣A−B∣=∣A∣−∣B∣

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Let $Y_0=A$ and $Y_n=Y_{n-1} \setminus {b_n}$, where $b_i\in B, i>0$.
This gives the base case and the inductive step respectively.
Then $|Y_n|=|Y_{n-1}|-1$.
As $|B|=k$, then $Y_k=A\setminus B$, and so $|Y_k|=|Y_0|-k=|A|-|B|$.
